# The recovery model cannot be changed to SIMPLE when any files are subject to a RESTORE PAGE operation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of my pages in database needed restore. so I did a restoration by this command:

```
USE master RESTORE DATABASE myDB PAGE = '1:4171728'FROM DISK = 'D:\Backups\Database\myDB.bak 'WITH NORECOVERY"
```

The problem with that page was solved. But another problem occurred.  I cannot do a backup or change a recovery model. The error is:

> Backup of file 'myDB' is not permitted because it contains pages subject to an online restore sequence. Complete the restore sequence before taking the backup, or restrict the backup to exclude this file.

What should I do?

I tried DBCC CheckDB and no errors. Database works fine. But unable to perform a backup nor changing a recovery model.

Comment: Asking for urgent help is against the T&C for this site. If you question is clear, someone will answer when they get a chance to do so.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#to-restore-pages-1), the `restore database yourDB page...` statement is step 2. Did you perform the subsequent steps which amount to "then apply other backups to bring that page up to current", "back up the log once all that is done", and "restore _that_ log with recovery"?

Comment: No I didn't. I only had a full backup and with that I did "restore database myDB page..."